# Select all attribute values from given rows (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following structure:

```
<ul id="myTags"">
   <li>
     <span class="tagit-label">AA</span>
     <a>
        <span class="text-icon">×</span>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close"></span>
     </a>
     <input type="hidden" name="tags" value="AA" style="display:none;">
   </li>
   <li>
     <span class="tagit-label">BB</span>
     <a class="tagit-close">
        <span class="text-icon">×</span>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close"></span>
     </a>
     <input type="hidden" name="tags" value="BB" style="display:none;">
   </li>
   ....
</ul>
```

I want to write a Javascript/jQuery function that will create a string consists of

```
"AA,BB,..."
```

How do I collect the values from all of the value attribute at span rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('#myTags input[name="tags"]').map(function () {
    return $(this).val();
}).get().join(",");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var textArr = [];
$(".tagit-label").each(function(){
  textArr.push($(this).text());
})
console.log(textArr.join());
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

```
var array = $('.tagit-label').map(function(){
    return $(this).text()
}).get()

console.log(array.join(','))
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3rRYQ/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
var arr = $('#myTags .tagit-label').map(function () {
    return $(this).text();
}).get().join(",");

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my late answer. I tried javascript 1.8 array `reduce` method, for fun .

```
var string = [].reduce.apply( $('.tagit-label') , [ function( ar , n ){          
     return ar.push( $(n).text() ) && ar ;
},[] ] ).join();
```

or simply

```
var string = [].reduce.call( $('.tagit-label') , function( ar , n ){          
     return ar.push( n.innerHTML ) && ar ;
},[] ).join();
```

Hope this will help learning more on `reduce` method . http://jsfiddle.net/6TnMT/

Comment: You can use `.call()` instead of `.apply()` so that you don't need to wrap your arguments in an Array, and then you might as well seed it with an empty string, and do `[].reduce.call($('.tagit-label'), function(s, n){ return s.concat($(n).text());
}, "");`

Comment: ...oh, except that OP wanted commas. Missed that. Could add `, ","` to the concat, but then you'd need to trim the trailing `","`.

Comment: @squint .. updated answer .. `s.concat($(n).text());` and add logic to find end of string to trim away `","` , I think it will reduce readability!

Comment: Just a matter of preference I guess. `[].reduce.call($('input[name=tags]'), function(s, n){ return s.concat(n.value, ","); }, "").slice(0,-1)`. Still, if you're going to push into an Array, then `.map()` would make more sense. But +1 for `.reduce()` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var spans = $(".tagit-label");
    var str = "";
    for (i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {

        str += spans[i].innerHTML+"," ;
    }
    alert(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/c4K9y/)

```
var str= $('.tagit-label').first().text();
    $('.tagit-label:not(":first")').each(function(){
        str= str +' , '+ $(this).text();
    });
    alert(str);
```